# Periodic sending small data to server in background mode

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, multitasking

I am implementing a kind of tracking app and i need to spot my location once and send it once per 10 - 20 seconds (period value is important and can't be exceeded).
To lower battery consumption i stop location updates. This works good in foreground, but how can i do it when app moved in background?
I looked info about background fetch, but it hasn't got precise time for periodic sending data

How can i perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start and Stop periodic location update while app is in background.
To achieve this add class from given link for [Location Update](https://github.com/voyage11/Location).

After that import LocationTracker.h in your AppDelegate.

Add Below code in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
let locationTracker : LocationTracker  = LocationTracker();
locationTracker?.startLocationTracking();
```

In LocationTracker.m, you can set duration to restart update.Here i set 1 minute or 60 Seconds.

```
//Restart the locationMaanger after 1 minute
self.shareModel.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self
                                                       selector:@selector(restartLocationUpdates)
                                                       userInfo:nil
                                                        repeats:NO];
```

You can also set duration time for fetch Locations. Here I fetch location for 10 Seconds.

```
self.shareModel.delay10Seconds = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self
                                                selector:@selector(stopLocationDelayBy10Seconds)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];
```